# Replace the text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using the below code to replace the text within the h1 tag, but its not getting effected. I want to replace "sample" to "new sample". I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="content">
<h2>sample</h2>
</div>

var t = jQuery('.content');
        t.children("h2").each(function() {
            var contents = jQuery(this).contents();
            jQuery(this).replaceWith(new sample);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace some part of content then try this:

```
jQuery('.content h2').each(function(i, v) {
    $v = $(v);
    $v.html($v.html().replace('sample', 'new sample'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/7qpWX/)**

Comment: Thank You, I actually wanted this code. Because I have same div class repeated twice, so this will replace only targeted div.

Answer (score 2):

use `.html()` to set html.try this:

```
 $('.content h2').html('new sample');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm7CQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Set [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
t.children("h2").text('new sample'));
```

---

If you want to set [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) content

```
t.children("h2").html('new sample'));
```

---

[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('.content > h2').html('new sample');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .text()

```
$(".content h2").text("new sample");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDLLp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without jQuery:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
elem.innerHTML = "New Value";
```